okhttp client's callTimeout not respected
My Java project uses okhttp3 version 4.2.0.
I set callTimeout 400ms for client, but when I watch online server log, that request gets cancelled after 34606ms
Btw, when this happens, the cpu load is not high.
I would like to know why this happens and naturally how to fix.
Thank you!
@Slf4j
@Component
public class SecurityApi {

    private static final OkHttpClient CLIENT = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .callTimeout(400, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).build();

    private static final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public CheckResultVO checkContent(String content, Integer msgClass, String order) {
            SecurityCheckDTO securityCheckDTO = buildSecurityCheckDTO(content, msgClass);
            String length = (content == null || content.length() < 100) ? SecurityExecuteMetricConstants.LENGTH_SHORT : SecurityExecuteMetricConstants.LENGTH_LONG;

            try {
                okhttp3.MediaType mediaType = okhttp3.MediaType.parse(org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
                RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(securityCheckDTO), mediaType);
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(SECURITY_URL)
                        .addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                        .method("POST", requestBody)
                        .build();
                log.info("call security openapi, url: {}\n header: {}\n requestBody: {}", SECURITY_URL,
                        request.headers().toMultimap(), JSONObject.toJSONString(securityCheckDTO));

                long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                try (Response response = CLIENT.newCall(request).execute()) {
                    long costTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                    if (response.body() == null) {
                        log.error("call security openapi, response is null");
                        return CheckResultVO.legal();
                    }

                    String responseBody = response.body().string();
                    log.info("[call security openapi responseBody]: {} msgClass: {} costTime: {}", responseBody, msgClass, costTime);

                    SecurityCheckVO securityCheckVO = objectMapper.readValue(responseBody, SecurityCheckVO.class);
                    if(securityCheckVO.getDecision() != null && securityCheckVO.getDecision().getErrCode() != 0) {
                        JSONObject errMsg = new JSONObject();
                        errMsg.fluentPut("content", content)
                                .fluentPut("msg_class", securityCheckDTO.getMsgClass());

                        if(securityCheckVO.getDecision() != null) {
                            errMsg.fluentPut("tips", securityCheckVO.getDecision().getErrMsg());
                        }
                        return CheckResultVO.illegal(errMsg.toJSONString(), securityCheckDTO.getMsgClass());
                    }

                    CheckResultVO legal = CheckResultVO.legal();

                    // metric
                    doMetric(msgClass, costTime, SecurityExecuteMetricConstants.EXECUTE_SUCCESS, length);
                    return legal;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    long costTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
                    log.error("[call security openapi failed] order: {} msg_class:{} the error message: {} costTime: {}",
                            order, msgClass, e.getMessage(), costTime, e);

                    // metric
                    doMetric(msgClass, costTime, SecurityExecuteMetricConstants.EXECUTE_FAIL, length);
                    return CheckResultVO.legal();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("[validContent failed] order: {} msg_class {} the error message: {}", order, msgClass, e.getMessage(), e);
                return CheckResultVO.legal();
            }
        } else {
            return CheckResultVO.legal();
        }
}


Are you using the wrong client, CLIENT_ATTACKING, isn't being used in this snippet.

sorry, this code is not complete, the client used just is CLIENT_ATTACKING

@思远陈 if the code is not complete please provide a [example], not just a vague snippet of code.

@思远陈 Have you tried setting .connectTimeout instead of .callTimeout? OkHttpClient has many different timeouts that you can use.

@Rawley Fowler yes, I have set connectTimeout, readTimeout, writeTimeout before, but this also happened. I think this is not timeouts problem, since connectTimeout, readTimeout, writeTimeout has default value 1s
